What is the advantage of 1's complement over 2's complement?
I understand that the clear advantage of 2's complement over 1's complement is the fact that it only has one value for zero. If that is the case, why was the 1's complement system ever used in the first place?
I was also able to find the following statement favouring 1's complement online:

Ones' complement subtraction can also result in an end-around borrow (described below). It can be argued that this makes the addition and subtraction logic more complicated or that it makes it simpler, as a subtraction requires simply inverting the bits of the second operand as it is passed to the adder.


Aside: the proposed C23 coding standard (for C code) mandates the use of 2's complement for integers.

See also https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7095/why-did-ones-complement-decline-in-popularity and https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24025/why-was-ones-complement-integers-implemented.

In fact, I think this is a duplicate of the latter question.

Signed zero is not very useful.

1's complement representation is symmetrical (neg/pos), so no possibility of overflow on negation.

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen OTOH a signed 0 floating point value is useful.

@WeatherVane yes.  But floating point was rarely implemented in cpu hardware.

Using ones'-complement allows a subtraction to be performed using a combination of "flip all bits" and an ordinary "add", without needing a separate "add with extra carry" instruction.  It also facilitates certain forms of I/O, such as outputting numbers in signed binary or signed octal format.  For example, a display panel which is supposed to show positive numbers using green blinkenlights and negative numbers using red blinkenlights could wire a row of green blinkenlights to run on if the sign bit is clear and the corresponding bit in the register is also set, and a row of red blinkenlights to turn on if the sign bit is set but the corresponding bit in the register isn't.  Incidentally, similar issues arise with adding machines using nines'-complement.
For some tasks, those advantages could have been significant, but in all other respects two's-complement (or ten's-complement) is just plain better.

I don't see how the described above could be a real advantage. In two's complement machines it is adder, not instruction, that would subtract given the subtrahend is bitwise-inverted and carry-in is set to 1 instead of 0. However, one's complement machine must pass carries twice around the whole adder (carry-around can't happen more than once but carry propagation times double anyway), so you're trading the need to have carry-in for the need to have carry-around.

You're assuming code could somehow control the carry going into the ADD instruction.  I expect the design probably flows from mechanical adding machines, some of which included an extra "+1" key when doing nines'-complement subtraction, and relied upon people to manually invert negative totals, but some of which could add or subtract arbitrary sequences of numbers and output positive or negative totals directly.  If a system has mechanism to identify which digits have carried and which ones are nines, processing an extra carry at the end will be simpler than performing a general addition...

...since the only digits affected will be the rightmost string of nines, and the rightmost digit that isn't nine.  Applying a nines'-complement extra carry into the sum that was just computed is simpler than having to adjust a ten's-complenent number prior to printing and then adjust it back afterward (the print mechanism can have two cammed surfaces on each printing element, one for normal readout and one for nines' complement).

First of all I'm speaking about binary machines. Then, some ISAs have explicit control over carry-in (for example, Z80, 6502), some probably not. But still, even in the last case the subtraction could be very well done the way described with carry-in controlled by the decoded insn or insn decoder FSM. You are right that the finishing increment for carry-around could be done faster than a proper carry propagation through the adder, however it's still lots of logic in comparison with carry-in for the adder in two's complement system.

@lvd: I expect the designers of binary machines were likely inspired by the design of mechanical predecessors.  When you talk about the carry-in being controlled by the instruction decoder, that's presupposing the existence of separate ADD and SUB instructions.
